# AHK Win key weirdness: sends 'Ctrl' at random or allows the rebound keys to still activate

Tags: autohotkey

The following script allows `Win+X` and `Win+Z` to be used for scrolling, and disables the Windows key bringing the Start menu up, as suggested in the documentation:

```
#z::
    Send  {WheelDown 1}
    Return

#x::
    Send {WheelUp 1}
    Return

~LWin::
    Send {Blind}{vkE8}
    Return
```

However, these hotkeys sometimes

- cause zoom-in or zoom-out (i.e. Ctrl + Scrolling),
- cause undo (i.e. Ctrl + Z),
- or cause the Win + X menu to pop up.

None of these are intended. So, why are they happening, how to prevent them?

Sometimes I find other combinations that use the Windows key to do this kind of nonsense too.

These issues are easy to recreate with the above script just by spamming the hotkeys.

Comment: Works fine here and without disabling the Windows key. Try it first in a script with no other code and close all other scripts. And install the latest AHK version.

Comment: I did and I did before posting.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your keyboard, I suppose. Needs cleaning?